# How does Lydia "escape" the dinner scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, beetlejuice

During the dinner scene, when Beetlejuice tries to get the Deetz to leave the house for the first time, they all (except Lydia) get possessed and start to dance to the Banana Boat Song:

At around 00:53 (timestamp based on the YouTube clip above), Lydia just stands up and goes away. At no point in time does she seem to follow the others' movement. Everyone else seems to be bound to the table, unable to move on their own.

Is this ever explained? Is it because she's "special" (same reason she's able to see the Maitlands)? Or did Beetlejuice cast an eye on her already? Or was this the work of the Maitlands only? If so, how did they learn to summon the hands from the shrimp cocktails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the work of the Maitlands **only.**
About the hands... I believe that it was as easy as turn their faces into horror.

Saludos

Comment: Sorry, I had problems with the language and tried to be short.

Comment: Ok, I think that the hands were their hands through the table. I don't know exactly why they were more than 4, but I suspect that it have no explanation.. it was absurd. 
But it's obvious that the "bananas bout scene" was a work of the Maitlands, because they want to scare the Deetz (and they didn't pronounced Beetlejuice's name) and that's because Lydia did not dance, they haven't needed to scare her

Comment: Don't worry, the answer is perfectly clear. And yeah, it seems I so far I never noticed the Maitlands trying it one more time. Watched it again and it's indeed Lydia who'll then summon/free Beetlejuice later on during the seance.